# Problems with push_back in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I'm creating a graph class in c++ but having some problems to insert elements into it. The graph is implemented using a `vector<vector<Edge> >` simulating a linked_list.

Here is my main.cc:
http://pastebin.com/xkamm7Jq

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include "edge.h"
#include "graph.h"
#include "vertex.h"

using namespace std;

int main (){

  int n, m;
  cin >> n >> m;

  Graph g (n);    
  for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
    int node, cost;
    cin >> node >> cost;    
    g[i].push_back (Edge (node, cost));
    cout << g[i].size() << endl;
  }

  cout << g.size() << endl;
  for (int i=0; i<g.size(); i++){
    cout << g[i].size() << endl;
  }    
  return 0;
}
```

Graph.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "vertex.h"

#ifndef _graph_h
#define _graph_h

class Graph {
 private:
  std::vector<Vertex> graph;

 public:
  Graph ();
  Graph (int size);
  Graph (int size, Vertex vertices);

  ~Graph();

  int size ();
  void resize (int size);
  void push_back (Vertex vertex);

  Vertex operator [] (int pos);


};

#endif
```

Here is graph.cc:

```
#include "graph.h"

Graph::Graph (){
  //
}

Graph::Graph (int size){
  this->graph.resize (size);
}

Graph::Graph (int size, Vertex vertices){
  this->graph.resize (size);
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    this->graph[i] = vertices;
}

Graph::~Graph (){
  std::cout << "destruiu grafo\n";
}

int Graph::size (){
  return this->graph.size();
}

void Graph::resize (int size){
  this->graph.resize (size);
}

void Graph::push_back (Vertex vertex){
  this->graph.push_back (vertex);
}

Vertex Graph::operator [] (int pos){
  return this->graph[pos];
}
```

Vertex.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include "edge.h"

#ifndef _vertex_h
#define _vertex_h

class Vertex {
 private:
  int node;
  std::vector<Edge> edges;

 public:
  Vertex ();
  Vertex (int node);
  Vertex (int node, std::vector<Edge> edges);
  Vertex (const Vertex& other);
  ~Vertex ();

  int getNode ();
  void push_back (Edge edge);
  std::vector<Edge> getEdges ();

  int size();

  Vertex operator = (const Vertex& other);

  Edge operator [] (int pos);


};

#endif
```

Vertex.cc

```
#include "vertex.h"
#include <iostream>

Vertex::Vertex (){

}

Vertex::Vertex (int node){
  this->node = node;
}

Vertex::Vertex (int node, std::vector<Edge> edges){
  this->node = node;
  this->edges = edges;
}

Vertex::Vertex (const Vertex& other){
  this->node = other.node;
  this->edges = other.edges;
}

Vertex::~Vertex (){

}

Vertex Vertex::operator = (const Vertex& other){
  this->node = other.node;
  this->edges = other.edges;
  return *this;
}

int Vertex::getNode (){
  return this->node;
}

std::vector<Edge> Vertex::getEdges (){
  return this->edges;
}

void Vertex::push_back (Edge edge){
  this->edges.push_back (edge);
}

int Vertex::size (){
  return this->edges.size();
}

Edge Vertex::operator [] (int pos){
  return this->edges[pos];
}
```

Edge.h:

```
#ifndef _edge_h
#define _edge_h

class Edge {
 private:
  int node;
  int cost;    
 public:
  Edge (int node, int cost);
  Edge (const Edge& other);
  ~Edge ();

  Edge operator = (const Edge& other);
  void setNode (int node);
  int getNode ();
  int getCost ();
};

#endif
```

and Edge.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "edge.h"

Edge::Edge (int node, int cost){
  this->node = node;
  this->cost = cost;
}

Edge::Edge (const Edge& other){
  this->node = other.node;
  this->cost = other.cost;
}

Edge::~Edge (){
  std::cout << "edge deleted\n";
}

Edge Edge::operator = (const Edge& other){
  this->node = other.node;
  this->cost = other.cost;    
  return *this;
}

int Edge::getNode (){
  return this->node;
}

int Edge::getCost (){
  return this->cost;
}

void Edge::setNode (int node){
  this->node = node;
}
```

My problem is related to the `g.push_back()`. Just after the push, the element (in this case, `Edge`) is deleted from the `vector<Edge>`.

I know that a `vector` copies the element during the insertion but apparently, he is holding a reference to the object declared on main ().

Here is an example:

```
  for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
    int node, cost;
    cin >> node >> cost;

    g[i].push_back (Edge (node, cost));
    cout << g[i].size() << endl;
  }
```

The `cout` will always give me 0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "the element is deleted from the vector"? You means the destructor is called?

Comment: Just after the insertion, the size of the vector back to be 0. As if I had not inserted anything

Comment: Yes, the destructor of the Edge () is called.

Comment: You'll get more/better answers if you 1. create a **minimal** example showing the issue. and 2. Put the code for that minimal example in your question, rather than forcing people off-site.

Comment: The destructor is called because of some temporary objects. But it is strange that the size of g[i] is 0 after you call g[i].push_back(xxx).

Comment: I think you can also provide the definition of Graph.

Comment: How is `Graph` defined? Better post that code also

Comment: `Graph::operator[]` returns a vector by value - that is, it returns a temporary. It is in that temporary that you `push_back`. Of course, the temporary is destroyed soon afterwards. The second call to `g[i]` produces a fresh, empty temporary vector.

Comment: I think it should be okay if you: typedef vector<vector<Edge>> Graph;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Vertex& Graph::operator [] (int pos){
  return this->graph[pos];
}
```

And add another just for retrieval

```
const Vertex& Graph::operator [] (int pos)const{
  return this->graph[pos];
}
```

And just a reminder, not related to the question, but it is good to make use of `const` for all get methods.